# My PS3 keeps freezing on a mission

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I have completed only 10 percent of the game. The problem is that I'm not able to start a mission. I have done rest of the available missions. The name of the mission is *CHOP* 
The game stops or crashes whenever I reach the green "F" by using Franklin and I have to restart my ps3. 
I have restarted the game twice and even completed it till 10% but the mission won't start. Please help.

Comment: Is the disk scratched? Does your PS3 freeze with any other game?  Is there proper ventilation for your PS3?

Comment: No it is not scratched. No it does not freeze with any other game. This is not the problem because I have 2 disks! I have tried with both. This is still happening @zerostack

Comment: Seeing as you are only 10% in... have you tried deleted game data (your save) and start over?

Comment: yes I have deleted the game data. and started the game from the first mission. the game works totally fine till that mission only. even when I am around the house of franklin. it crashes

Comment: What is your PS3 model? Certain models are prone to freezing and screwing up with GTA V, I know this from experience.

Comment: I Did the re installation by deleting it fron the game utility. The 8474 MB thing. It worked :) thanks for your help guys :)